# How do I elegantly write a List<object[]> collection of mixed types to an Excel worksheet using C#?

Tags: c#, excel

I have a C# add-in that gathers data from a 3rd-party application (via COM) and then writes it to an Excel spreadsheet. The main data is in the form of what can be conceptually viewed as a 2D array, but in C# is stored as a List<object[]> collection. Each List member is a different item in a collection of like things (e.g. Pumps - it is an engineering task), and each member is represented by an object[] array, because some of the properties/attributes are string and others are numeric.

I want to essentially write my List<object[]> structure to an Excel sheet in as few sheet I/O operations as possible, for speed, but cannot quite work out how this might be done.

Let's assume I have already got a C# object reference to the top-left Excel.Range (rng) object of the sheet I want to write to (using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel - henceforth let's call it "xl" - reference). I know there is a .Count method on the List to get one dimension, and I assume I can use .Length on the object[] to get the other.

Is there a C#-like way of casting the entire structure to a 2D rng.Value2 object? I am open to making a custom class instead of generic "object[]" to hold my mixed-type data, so that I can do a method that casts the underlying data on retrieval. I think all my data has the same type across different List members, for a given element of the object[] array i.e. object[0] is always a string.

Comment: what's stopping you from defining your custom type as class or struct ?

Comment: when you know, `object[0]` is allways a string, `[1]` is allways an int and so on, just create a simple class with all these columns as properties and their correspconding type. This is way easier to serialize to whatever file-format than reyling on `object`. Otherwise you'd need to do all the type-checking yourself, which is cumbersome and painful.

Comment: I have not made a custom type yet because I was hoping for a faster solution, and am still picking C# up - I'm an engineer not a programmer. I even considered doing some sort of try-catch bulk casting to a numeric type, falling back to string for those that fail. That would work for me because I know all my data are either <double> or <string>.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain, I considered this but it doesn't work because I am using a generic class to contain different blocks of same-type data - hard to explain, but my ultimate aim is a collection/array of my List<object[]> - one List<object[]> gets written to each Excel sheet. So for each instance of my class, the length and contents of the objects[] array is different, but all List items within that class instance are the same, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign every object[i] to an Excel cell. You don't need to perform any conversion/type recognition, Excel does it itself.

Also you can set a Range at once:

```
oSheet.Range["F4:H4"].Value = new object[] { 1, "Hello, World!", DateTime.Now };
```

It can looks like:

```
List<object[]> myinputdata;
...
var i = 1;
foreach (var itm in myinputdata) {
    var j = itm.Length;
    oSheet.get_Range(oSheet.Cells[i, 1], oSheet.Cells[i, j]).Value = itm;
    i++;
}
```

2D array operation is allowed as well:

```
oSheet.Range["F4:H5"].Value = new object[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };
```

You can convert your list into a 2D object array first then write it to a Range at once:

```
List<object[]> myinputdata = new List<object[]> { new object[] { 1, 2 }, new object[] { 3, 4, 5 } };
int mc = myinputdata.Count, ml = 0, i = -1, j;
foreach (var itm in myinputdata) ml = itm.Length > ml ? itm.Length : ml;
object[,] oa = new object[mc, ml];
foreach (var itm in myinputdata)
    for (i++, j = 0; j < itm.Length; j++) oa[i, j] = itm[j];
Sheet.get_Range(oSheet.Cells[1, 1], oSheet.Cells[mc, ml]).Value = oa;
```

**P. S.** You can create an extension method to perform this conversion:

```
static class Utilities {
    static object[,] To2DArray(this List<object[]> loa) {
        var ml = 0;
        foreach (var itm in loa) ml = itm.Length > ml ? itm.Length : ml;
        object[,] oa = new object[loa.Count, ml];
        int i = -1, j;
        foreach (var itm in loa)
            for (i++, j = 0; j < itm.Length; j++) oa[i, j] = itm[j];
        return oa;
    }
}
// usage
var readyForExcel= myinputdata.To2DArray();
```

Comment: Presumably the casting of the interim object "oa" is required to 'flatten' the structure into something that Excel can be passed as a 2D array to map to cells?

Comment: Otherwise that seems like a good option - I will try it an see whether it is performant enough. I suspect it will be faster than the VBA I am replacing - although at least the VBA currently just builds a 2D Variant and writes it directly to the sheet in one go.

Comment: Excel accepts the 2D arrays, thus I converted the list to an array. I guess a list is not accepting (didn't check).

Comment: 'flatten' is little bit not the correct term. `List<object[]>` is the 2D structure as well as `object[,]`. Just List is not accepted by Excel.

Comment: For completeness, this approach broadly worked, thanks @rotabor. I ended up using slightly different route to get the row and column count (I am grabbing from get methods on a class that holds the data), and I had to flip your i and j around in the for loop, but otherwise great advice, thanks!

Comment: Final comment - I did try writing the List<object[]> structure directly to Excel, but the interop assembly did not accept it. This is a neat workaround, which I shall probably wrap in its own class as I'll need it many times!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel is not a very fast way of doing this - it's quite slow in fact.

This is a suggestion, not an answer to your question, but may answer your question all the same.

If you can cast the "object" to a type then you could override the ToString() method to output a single line of text, something like this;

```
var output = new StringBuilder();
YourType item;

foreach(var obj in YourCollection)
{
    item = (YourType) obj;
    output.AppendLine(item.ToString());
}

return output.ToString();

// Write "output" to a csv file
```

You override the ToString method to output a coma-delimited, tab-delimited or pipe-deliminted string that can be added to the StringBuilder that is ultimately the contents of your csv file.
eg;

```
public class YourType
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }

    public int? Prop2 { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{this.Prop1}\t{this.Prop2.HasValue ? this.Prop2 : 0}";
    }
}
```

I realise this isn't what you asked for but hopefully there's something there you can use - check the performance difference!

Comment: Thanks for the idea - in this particular case I cannot use it, because I am reading user choices from a template file and writing results back to output sheets within said file. So my output is not just a dumb Excel-like CSV, it is actually defined cells in a specific Excel workbook, if that makes sense? I do like your methodology though, in terms of trying to override a string - I may have some other uses for that approach, so thanks!